# How to use MVC in Java EE 6/7 without using other frameworks?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller

I have already implemented the `MVC` pattern using the Spring framework.
In Spring there are `@Controller` and `@RequestMapping` annotations in the controller class and  this framework doesn't use any `HttpServlet`.

I want this exact structure in Java EE (but without using any other framework).

So my question is: how can I use MVC in Java EE without using other frameworks?
Note: I don't want to use `HttpServlet` class

Comment: You want MVC, but don't want spring? Is that correct?

Comment: yes, I don't want to use any framework.

Comment: Why? And `HttpServlet` is kind of central to all web-based j2ee things...

Comment: To be clear, JSF implements the MVC pattern and is part of Java EE. The way JSF implements it is different than how it's done in Spring MVC. Arguably JSF is closer to the original MVC model introduced by Smalltalk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1)

You can use JAX-RS and CDI to respond to HTTP requests, using annotations such as @Path and @RequestScoped. You might need some JAX-RS extensions or utilities for convenience, for better handling of parameters (e.g. RestEasy's @Form) and forwards to views (e.g. Jersey's Viewable).

(2)

You can also write a single HttpServlet (I hope that's not a problem) that will act as a front controller, instantiating the controller for each request. Using CDI, you can annotate your controllers with @Model (which is the same as @RequestScoped and @Named), and instantiate them in your front controller with:

```
@Inject @Any
private Instance<ControllerBaseClass> controllerInstance;

(...)

ControllerBaseClass controller = controllerInstance.select(«something»).get();
controller.processRequest(); // or execute() or anything you want.
request.getRequestDispatcher(«page»).forward(request, response); // or a redirect if it's a destructive operation.
```

What do you need to pass to select(«something»)? You can select an instance in CDI using annotation literals (consult CDI documentation) or classes (Class.forName(...)), depending on the request parameters.

Using CDI you can also make your controllers @ApplicationScoped instead of @RequestScoped.

As you see, you may need to build some infrastructure and stick to some patterns from then on, but it's perfectly feasible. I have used a mix of both strategies in a personal project and it works fine.

Comment: ok @marcus I will try it and mark it as accepted if it works..
if you have some tutorial links please share it. Thanks

Comment: I don't have any specific tutorial, but I suggest consulting the documentation for these projects: RestEasy (JAX-RS): http://resteasy.jboss.org/ ; Weld (CDI) http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/ ; DeltaSpike (small CDI extensions, notice that Java EE 7 already has some CDI improvements over Java EE 6) https://deltaspike.apache.org/ ; and you can read the source of your favorite open-source frameworks to learn about type conversion, ThreadLocals, reflection, CSRF tokens, HTML and JavaScript escaping, conversation/flash scope, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with technologies available in Java EE.

It's important to mention that Java EE is itself composed of many specifications/frameworks, for which there are more implementations. See this: https://java.net/projects/javaee-spec/pages/Home

Example with JSF http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_architecture.htm
Example with JSP http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/jsp/jsp_mvc_tutorial.htm
Another example with JAX-RS https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/mvc.html

JSF is much more feature rich than JSP, and there are many components already made for it: Omnifaces, Primefaces etc. JAX-RS is for web services.
Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

By simply using `EJB` for business logic, `CDI` for bean management and `JSF` for view.

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect to say that with Spring MVC there is no `HttpServlet`. From Spring Framework javadoc : `DispatcherServlet` (a subclass of `HttpServlet`) is  the *Central dispatcher for HTTP request handlers/controllers* of the Spring framework. So it's hidden in the framework but present.

In fact, except in JSP only applications (not really MVC ... and JSP are translated in ... Servlets !) or JSF applications, you have (subclasses of) `HttpServlet` in all Java EE applications. And as JSF is only a specification you have to use an *implemantation* of JSF. There are 2 well known implementations, Oracle Mojarra or Apache MyFaces but both are ... frameworks.

Of course, you can do MVC in Java EE without any framework. As explained in [Model View Component on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) MVC is a design patter independant of any of its implementations. The hard part will be no `HttpServlet`.